# Backbone.js - how to send a non-state "event" from one view to another?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller

Let's say I have an application with two views that are connected - some sort of a form element in the main content area, and a "sidebar" which stores a summary of the form in question.

I'd like to create a simple "flash" animation on both the text input itself and the view that represents it in the summary.  These two views are in very distant parts of the DOM tree, so it is not practical to register them as sub-views of their parents and bubble the event up that way.  So, the form field (a simple input type="text") has this model

```
//The model that manages these two views
var InputModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        flash: false
    }
})



//The view of the input field in the actual form - its this.model is an instance of InputModel
var InputFormView = Backbone.Model.extend({
    events: {
        'mousedown': 'clicked'
    }

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
        this.model.on('change:flash', this.flash, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        return this; //The 'el' DOM element is passed to this view on creation
    },

    clicked: function() {
        this.model.set('flash', true);
    },

    flash: function(model) {
        if (model.changed.flash && model.changed.flash === true){
            //Do the 'flashing' animation using jQuery animate
        } else {
            this.model.set('flash', false);
        }
    }
});



//The summary column view - its this.model is an instance of InputModel
var InputSummaryView = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
        this.model.on('change:flash', this.flash, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        return this; //The 'el' DOM element is passed to this view on creation
    },

    flash: function(model) {
        if (model.changed.flash && model.changed.flash === true){
            //Do the 'flashing' animation using jQuery animate
        } else {
            this.model.set('flash', false);
        }
    }
});
```

This defintely works in practice.  The problem I see is two-fold:

1. I now have attributes in my model that are not useful data about the input.  As in, whether 'flash' is true or not is not semantically useful information - it is strictly related to the "presentation" of the data, not the content of the data itself, and thus should be relegated to the views.
2. The flash field will either clog up my DB with useful information, or I'll need to filter it out every time I save().

Is there any way to avoid this problem?  To have the two very distant views engage in event- based communication without using (or at least mucking up) their shared model?

Comment: backbone models extend from the Events class, so you can listen for and trigger custom events with `on` and `trigger`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're definitely correct that you don't want to pollute the model with that data. There's actually a much more straightforward option: use an event manager. Create an object whose sole job is to trigger and respond to events globally in your app. Happily, [`Backbone.Events`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) can do this for you, as the docs suggest:

```
var dispatcher = _.clone(Backbone.Events);
```

Then, you can just do `dispatcher.trigger('flash')` and `dispatcher.on('flash')` in your views. Although, I would rename the event to something more meaningful about what has actually happened.